# Nubia Red Magic 3 shows negative storage on some apps and it's driving my nuts

Tags: storage, bugs, magisk, systemless-root

Probably a bug but I still want to share exactly what's going on and hopefully find a solution. I can't use a logcat for some reason (Sepolicy issue maybe?) But anyways I own a Red Magic 3 and it's been a trouble from the start. Every once in a while apps crash, and I'm getting negative storage on many applications (not viewing my entire storage but viewing apps individually).

I'm on Android 9 btw.

This leads to many issues. One: If I need to clear an app data for ex. Snapchat, the storage will be negative and it will refuse to let me wipe the storage since it's in the negative. The "Clear Storage" button is greyed out.

This leads to a bogged down phone, apps don't run in the background correctly, notification bugs and overall a noticable change in how the phone feels in performance.

Google Play has recently stopped working completely and I believe it's the storage bug.

Second, the issue can be fixed by, unfortunately, factory resetting my Red Magic 3.

I also noticed that it seems to do this when Magisk is installed which leads me to believe there is a storage bug of some sort.

I've search many threads but none that fits the issue I'm looking at.

Any ideas what might be causing it? Could it be a major bug from Nubia?

I seriously regret getting a Nubia smartphone because I've heard bad things from the company. Customer support sucks, they take a long time to provide updates. I am trying to fix the logcat issue as of right now.